# Unexpected "100 continue"

Tags: http, windows-server-2003, remoting

I have 2 servers that communicates using .Net remoting. For some architectural reasons, I have a proxy between those 2 servers, that removes the "Expect: 100-continue" header from the request that is sent from one server to another. The problem is, that when the proxy sends the message to the second server without this header, the destination server responses with "100 continue". This behavior causes us many problems, since the proxy discards the whole http conversation, when it gets "100 continue".
I googled this issue, and I found that there was a bug in windows server 2003 SP1, which was supposed to be fixed in SP2, but after I installed it, the problem still remains.
Does anyone knows how to fix it, or to configure http.sys or remoting not to send the "100 continue"?

Comment: this looks like it is more suited to serverfault.com

Comment: Did you upgrade to SP2 on all servers involved?